# What does to (bar number) mean?

Tags: theory, piano

I'm currently learning the Addams family 2nd keyboard and there are 4 bars from 35-38 and then in brackets after those 4 bars, it says (to 47). Below those 4 bars, it then skips to bar 47 as said in the brackets. I'm a bit confused as to where did the other 8 bars go between 38 and 47? And do I just go on to bar 47 after bar 38 or do I just not play in between that period?

Comment: Can you post the part you mention? What the other instruments play at that time? Could it be there is a break or repetition in only in your instrument part?

Comment: This can't be answered definitively without seeing the part you're asking about. Presumably it's under copyright, so just the section in question is probably enough.

Comment: Just looked up the 1st piano part and it doesn't have the (to 47) it just goes from bar 38 to 47 directly. I assume that means they indeed cut it out as John said below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are playing the 2nd keyboard book from a musical it is probably a cut that has been put in by your production, or it might be a cut that has been made permanently. This happens a lot in different productions, bars, sections and even entire numbers may be cut to shorten the show or repeats or D.S. signs and codas are added to lengthen a number when deemed necessary by the production team. It sounds like your book had the cut edited into it so you don’t have bars 39-46 scratched out in your part.

As for whether or not those bars are there and you don’t play, if that were the case they would assign you rest bars.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. It's definitely a cut

Comment: It’s 8 bars which makes sense, and from your description of the part I would guess it’s been permanently removed from the show. The (to 47)  is there to explain the discrepancy in bar numbers, or it wasn’t removed when they reconstructed your part,